# Overenthusiastic moderation. Is there a feedback route?

Tags: discussion, new-users, moderation

Suppose there is a moderator on an unspecified Stack Exchange community who is sometimes, let us say, a little heavy handed—occasionally with very new members.

1. I understand that that is only my opinion.
2. This moderator has never, to my recollection, moderated anything of mine so there is no personal axe to grind.

I know that being a moderator is not easy and I would in any case not challenge a decision openly.

**Question**

Is there a recognised feedback route through which one can express such concerns without disrupting the efficient operation and good-will that exists here?

Comment: To prevent confusion, you are talking about those users with a diamond behind their name, right?

Comment: @rene - Yes, I mean with a diamond.

Comment: In that case the duplicate applies but if your case isn't covered then have you clarify why the dup isn't relevant here.

Comment: @vaultah - Thanks.  I read that 'duplicate' and none of the items covered there seemed relevant. I do not have any disputes, personal or otherwise. I am simply interested in giving constructive feedback.

Comment: Yes it is clearly covered there: *Send a message to the Stack Exchange team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page with your complaint and links to the questions/answers* - that's the "recognised feedback route" you asked for

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Okay thanks. No more questions.

Comment: You can also give public feedback and in some cases publicly reverse the action. For example if you think a question was overenthusiastically closed, you could comment on it to that effect, you could ask on the per site meta for clarification as to why it was closed, and you might be able to vote to reopen (perhaps after editing it.) If you think comments were unfairly cleared from a question you could comment to that effect, ask on Meta, and so on. Without details about what actions you think require feedback, it's very hard to answer this.